# Twitter's share ignores my data-url and data-text

Tags: twitter

Whatever I set data-url or data-text to, twitter just fetches the URL of the page the sharing button exists in and shows as the tweet-text.

example :

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/share" 
data-count="none" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.gogole.com" 
data-text="BLABLABLA" style="opacity:0">TWEET</a>
```

or

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/share" 
data-count="none" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="<?php echo 
urlencode('http://www.gogole.com')?>" data-text="BLABLABLA" style="opacity:0">TWEET</a>
```

in both cases, clicking on the link opens a new window with the twitter sharing box that includes the URL of **my** website and ignores the attributes I set.

Something should have gone dangly wrong. help appreciated ! 
please tell me if you need more info to be posted.

Thanks, 
/t

Comment: By itself I don't think this is going to do much, do you have any of the javascript? https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the query parameter "url" with the twitter share link "https://twitter.com/share"
When looking for the URL twitter button follow this priority:

1. Look for url in the share link query string
2. If not found, look for the data-url attribute of the Tweet Button anchor tag
3. If not found, look for the rel="canonical" link tag in the head of the document
4. If not found use the URL of the webpage

Answer (score 2):

I have faced same issue - when using link as described in manual's example it didnt work.

this NOT works:

```
<a class="twitterBtn smGlobalBtn" target=_blank href="https://twitter.com/share" data-text="my_title" data-url="my_url" data-hashtags="my_hash" data-via="my_name" data-related="my_name">Tweet</a>
```

but this WORKS:

```
<a class="twitterBtn smGlobalBtn" target=_blank href="https://twitter.com/share?text=my_text&url=my_url&hashtags=my_hash&via=my_name&related=my_name">Tweet</a>
```

Don't know why twitter ignores data- attributes, but when params are inside the link as GET params - everything works fine.

Hope this will be helpful for someone in future)

Comment: I'm having the same issue as this.  Worse, I have 2 pages on my website; on web page the data-* parameters are working as expected, and on the other page, ignored.  Leads me to believe that some content within my page is causing the issue but have yet to determine the issue.  For now I will resort to manually building the link tag.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by moving script **widgets.js** before button markup and turning off async mode, like this:

```html
<script src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="H..." />
```

**twitter-share-button** class also important.